# how to get seleted item from dropdown in textbox without postback in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

i have a dropdown that we populate from CascadingDropDown of ajax toolkit control. now i want to fill textbox based on item selected from dropdown without page postback

I tried that but it's not work

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event 
    $('#ddFeederOp').change(function () { 
        // Get Dropdownlist seleted item text 
        $("#FeederOpText").text($("#ddFeederOp option:selected").text()); 
        // Get Dropdownlist selected item value 
        return false; 
    }) 
});

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddPortOfDischarge" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox"> 
</asp:DropDownList> 

<ajax:CascadingDropDown ID="ccddPortOfDischarge" runat="server" Category="POD" 
ParentControlID="ddFeederOp" TargetControlID="ddPortOfDischarge" 
PromptText="Select" LoadingText="Loading ddPortOfDischarge.." 
ServiceMethod="BindPOD" ServicePath="~/DropdownWebService.asmx"> 
</ajax:CascadingDropDown>
```

Comment: Please add a code example of what you have already tried.

Comment: i tried that but it's not work.....................                                                               <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event
        $('#ddFeederOp').change(function () {
            // Get Dropdownlist seleted item text
            $("#FeederOpText").text($("#ddFeederOp option:selected").text());
            // Get Dropdownlist selected item value
            return false;
        })
    });
</script>

Comment: Please help me am tried lot of code ajax jquery but not work

Comment: Show your aspx with CascadingDropDown, DropDownList and TextBox

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddPortOfDischarge" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox">
                                                      
                                                </asp:DropDownList>

                                                <ajax:CascadingDropDown ID="ccddPortOfDischarge" runat="server" Category="POD" ParentControlID="ddFeederOp" TargetControlID="ddPortOfDischarge" PromptText="Select" LoadingText="Loading ddPortOfDischarge.." ServiceMethod="BindPOD" ServicePath="~/DropdownWebService.asmx">
                                         </ajax:CascadingDropDown>

Answer (score 0):

This `$("#FeederOpText").text(` must be `$("#FeederOpText").value(`

And better to use ClientID of server-side controls: `$("#<%= FeederOpText.ClientID %>")` instead of `$("#FeederOpText")`

Comment: when i use $("#<%= FeederOpText.ClientID %>") its give error <%.....................%>